# Java split byte[] array

Tags: java, массивы, byte

Есть большой массив с байтами:

```
byte[] binary = ...;
```

Как я могу разбить этот массив на несколько массивов при помощи такого разделителя:

```
byte[] split = new byte[]{0, 0x065, 4};
```

То есть нужно сделать то же самое, что и:

```
String default = "abcabcabcaaaa";
String split = "b";
String[] result = default.split("b");
```

но только с байтами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/29084734/1828296:

```
public static List<byte[]> tokens(byte[] array, byte[] delimiter) {
    List<byte[]> byteArrays = new LinkedList<>();
    if (delimiter.length == 0) {
        return byteArrays;
    }
    int begin = 0;

    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - delimiter.length + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < delimiter.length; j++) {
            if (array[i + j] != delimiter[j]) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        byteArrays.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, begin, i));
        begin = i + delimiter.length;
    }
    byteArrays.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, begin, array.length));
    return byteArrays;
}
```

Comment: Также можно глянуть здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1387184/1828296 (разбиение массива байт через преобразование к строке и использование regexp)